# excel Compile error: Can't assign to array

Tags: vba, excel, com

I am working on an Excel macro that uses several external references. Once in a while I get the error:

> excel Compile error:
>
> Can't assign to array

The highlighted line is an array assignments, not always the same. Something like:

```
Dim MyArray() As MyClass
MyArray = MyApplication.GetArrayOfElements
```

I get this error while the file is open on my computer once or twice per hour, after editing the VBA macro, especially (but not only) if I edit it while in break mode.

I usually compile before saving to make sure this problem is not there, but some users call me reporting this problem on their computer. So it looks like it breaks somewhere between my compilation and the next execution on another computer.

In order to get rid of the error all I need to do is to select all, cut, paste and compile (**Ctrl+A**, **Ctrl+X**, **Ctrl+V**, **Alt+D**, **L**.)

My wild guess is that it has to do with the VBA incremental compilation.

Anybody out there can help me get rid of this problem?

Comment: As a workaround, have you tried something like `Dim v As Variant : v = MyApplication.GetArrayOfElements : MyArray = v`?

Comment: I tried, but the error kept coming back in other lines. (I don't know if it changes line because this workaround gets rid of the error or because it just feels like it.) If the error moves to another assignment I can apply the same workaround, but now I got it in a line like `Set X = Object.AddGroup(Ents, Name, Origin)` where the function is defined as `Function AddGroup(pEntities() As ISmartId, groupName As String, pOrigin As IPoint) As TDGroup`, and it doesn't accept a Variant as argument. It's a third party library, and I can't change it.